# CD/DVD Drive not recognizing media

Tags: 12.04, cd-drive

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

I do think my CD/DVD drive is not working properly since it does not recognize the DVD+R that I insert. Using the Disk Utility program, it says there is no media in the drive. Are there possible drivers that I am missing?